# Constructing an example of a infinite set of triangles on the rational line whose union does not contain the interior of a rectangle.

Tags: general-topology, geometric-construction

As part of my Topology course, I saw a proof the following proposition (as a consequence of Baire's category theorem):

**Proposition**:
Define $\triangledown_{t,h}$ as the interior of an equilateral triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$, with the following three properties:

$(1)$ It's height is $h$.

$(2)$ One of it's edges is above, and parallel to, the $x$ axis.

$(3)$ One of it's vertices is located on the $x$ axis, at $(t,0)$.

Define $T:=\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}}\triangledown_{r,h_r}$,
where $h_r$ are arbitrary positive numbers. Then there is exists a rectangle with an edge on the $x$ axis, whose interior is in $T$.

---

Intuitively, it does not look like this proposition holds for unions over $\mathbb{Q}$. However, I could not construct a counterexample. I tried the following: Let  $q_n$ be an enumeration of the rationals, and set $T:=\bigcup_{q_n\in\mathbb{Q}}\triangledown_{q_n,\frac{1}{n}}$. By defining it this way, I ensure that there are only finitely many triangles above any given height. But I could not see how to continue from here.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

---

**Edit**: The original question was answered using the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a countable set. However, the above proposition is only proved for sets of the 2nd category. This might imply that there are uncountable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ of the 1st category (such as the Cantor set) for which the proposition does not hold. Can anyone give an example of such a set (or alternatively show that it holds for all uncountable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$)?

Comment: I may be off, but couldn't you inductively define the triangles so that the resulting collection is pairwise disjoint?

Comment: @DavidMitra Your suggestion is interesting. How would you construct such a collection?

Comment: Enumerate the rationals $\{r_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$. Let $T_1$ be arbitrary with bottom vertex $(0,r_1)$. Let $T_2$ be a triangle disjoint from $T_1$ with bottom vertex $(0,r_2)$. If $n$ pairwise disjoint triangles, $T_1,\ldots, T_n$ have been constructed with bottom vertices $r_1,\ldots, r_n$, it seems clear that a desired $T_{n+1}$ can be constructed. (Of course, I would not want to do this explicitly.)

Comment: @DavidMitra This seems good enough. If you elaborate just a little more, and post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @SomeStrangeUser: You can even take each triangle to have a right angle at the bottom vertex. For $n>1$ let $d_n=\min\{|r_n-r_k|:1\le k<n\}$; then setting $h_n=\frac12 d_n$ for $n>1$ works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if your example works or not, but here's an alternate method:

Fix an enumeration of the rationals $\{r_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$.

Show that there is a collection of triangles $\{T_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ satisfying your conditions, with the bottom vertex of $T_n$ at $( r_n,0)$, such that $T_n\cap T_m=\emptyset$ if $n\ne m$.

The union of the $T_n$ cannot contain the interior of a rectangle having an edge coinciding with the $x$-axis (this requires a small argument).

You can construct the required collection inductively. In the inductive step, assuming $T_1,\ldots, T_n$ have been constructed, note $F_n=T_1\cup\cdots\cup T_n$ is closed; so, there is an open disk centered at $(r_{n+1},0)$ disjoint from $F_n$ (of course, $(r_{n+1},0)\notin F_n$). Within this disc, you can construct $T_{n+1}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've edited my question, and added another part. I'd appreciate it if you could have a look, and perhaps provide a suggestion.

Comment: @SomeStrangeUser For the Cantor set, I think any collection of triangles would be a counterexample. Any open line segment on the $x$-axis that intersects the Cantor set would contain one of the "deleted intervals" from the construction of the Cantor set. It would thus contain two points $a$ and $b$ from the Cantor set that are endpoints of one of the deleted intervals. The triangles corresponding to $a$ and $b$ would omit a portion of any, supposedly contained, rectangle.